# Creating two copies of objects in a list

Tags: python, class, duplicates

I've been dying to figure this out but I just can' seem to get it working.

I have a class called Deck:

```
import random
class Deck(list):
'''
a list of cards represented in a deck
'''
def __init__(self):
    ''' a list of cards'''
    list.__init__(self)
    for i in range(52):
        self.append(Card(i))

def isEmpty(self):
    '''checks if Deck is empty or not; returns T or F'''
    return self(len) == 0

def shuffle(self):
    ''' shuffles the list of cards in random order'''
    return random.shuffle(self)

def deal(self, num):
    '''creates a new list of cards from the deck.
    Arguments:
        num = an integer to assign how many cards to deal
    Returns:
        a new list of cards taken from the deck
    '''
    new = []
    for i in range(num):
        x = self.pop(0)                    #something to note, if instead "x = self.pop(i)"
        new.append(x)                      #it will only take even card, and leave out odd cards
    return new

def restore(self, lst):
    '''restores the cards already taken from Deck
    Arguments:
        lst = a list of cards pulled out from Deck
    Returns:
        nothing; returns cards to the Deck
    '''
    while len(lst) > 0:
        x = lst.pop(0)
        self.append(x)
```

Class Deck is a list of object Cards, which is derived from class called Card.

Now I have to create this class called PinochleoDeck:

```
class PinochleDeck(Deck):

    def __init__(self):
        Deck.__init__(self)
        x = 0
        for i in range(4):
            for i in range(7):
                self.pop(x)
            x += 6
```

It's supposed to get decks only from 9 to Ace of all suits, which is 24 cards.
But I also have to make two copies of all cards so total of 48 cards as class PinochleoDeck.

I have tried so many things such as itertools, copy,and even brute multiplying but none of them worked.  How do I make two copies of objects in a list without creating a new list to do so the class PinocheloDeck has 48 cards?

Thanks

Comment: In what way did each attempt fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like all you are only removing a few of the cards on the first time through.  To get one copy of all 28 cards, you need to add one new line to your PinochleDeck class.  See below:

```
class PinochleDeck(Deck):

    def __init__(self):
        Deck.__init__(self)
        x = 0
        for i in range(4):
            for i in range(7):
                self.pop(x)
                x += 1  #NEED TO INCREMENT EVERY TIME THROUGH!!!
            x += 6
```

And to get two copies of each, you can just do something like this:

```
class PinochleDeck(Deck):

    def __init__(self):
        Deck.__init__(self)
        x = 0
        for i in range(4):
            for i in range(7):
                self.pop(x)
                x += 1  #NEED TO INCREMENT EVERY TIME THROUGH!!!
            x += 6
        self.extend(self)
```

Now, this will only work if you don't care about having multiple copies of the same instance (i.e. your cards won't change, so the ace of clubs will always look exactly the same).  If you need copies that are able to be modified without stepping on one-another, you will want to either perform a `deepcopy` on each card or quit using your `Deck` class's `__init__`.  I would go with:

```
class PinochleDeck(Deck):

    def __init__(self):
        list.__init__(self)

        for i in range(2):
            for suit_ind in range(4):
                for card_ind in range(7, 13):
                    self.append(Card(suit_ind*card_ind))
```

Comment: That gives a deck of only 16 cards.  You need to repeat the last line (self.append...) to make a copy of each card, and the range indices should be (7,13).  That will give you 9-spot through A of each suit,

Comment: Thanks a lot vorticity! I ended up just using three for loops to add the Cards instead of pop().  My loops turned out completely different than yours above but I used the same idea.  Thanks so much again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to deepcopy your list if you have a list of Card objects:

```
 from copy import deepcopy
```

To add them to the original list use extend:

```
 your_list.extend(deepcopy(your_list))
```

You also cannot call self `self(len)`